# Understanding conditional distribution and sampling for dependent variables

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, multivariate-distribution

Ok, so I am trying to see if I understand the following correctly.
Suppose I have a bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$..

Just as an example, suppose that $X,Y$ is distributed as:
$$\begin{align}
Y&\sim\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)\\
X&\sim Exponential(Y)
\end{align}$$

Then suppose I have a paired sample according to the following sampling strategy:
$$\begin{align}
For~i&\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\\
y_i&\sim\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)\\
x_i&\sim Exponential(y_i)
\end{align}$$

Then I wonder, will the $x_i$ samples of the marginal distribution of $X$ or the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$? My intuition tells me that it has to be the latter (because each $x$ is drawn, given the $y$ I drew before it) but I am not sure.

Comment: It seems that you are confusing yourself on terminology and notation.  If $(X,Y)$ are dependent, then $X$ is dependent on $Y$ and $Y$ is dependent on $X$.  Now the density of $(X,Y)$ can be obtained from the relation $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)$.  Clearly the marginals of $X$ and $Y$ are functionally independent of $Y$ or $X$, respectively, since these terms have been integrated out (i.e. $f_Y(y) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,y) \mbox{d}x$).  Since your $x_i$ depends on $y_i$, it must be a conditional distribution, and one should've written $x_i |y_i \sim Exp(y_i)$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing some of that up. Yeah, I think my notations and terminology are a bit off. But I am glad that at least it seems I got the conceptual understanding correct. So if I would multiply my $x_i$ samples with my $y_i$ samples and integreate over $y$, I'd get the marginal of $X$?

Comment: Yes that would obtain the marginal of $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the $X_i$ is simultaneously

1. distributed as $\mathcal Exp(y_i)$, conditional on $Y_i=y_i$
2. distributed from the marginal distribution
   $$f(x) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-xy_i)\,y_i\dfrac{\beta^\alpha y_i^{\alpha-1}\exp\{-\beta y_i\}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\,\text dy_i=\dfrac{\alpha\beta^\alpha}{(x+\beta)^{\alpha+1}}$$

The sample of the $X_i$'s is thus simultaneously

1. an iid sample from $f(x)$
2. a sequence of independent $\mathcal Exp(y_i)$ rv's, conditional on $\mathbf Y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$